# Proof that $41$ does not divide $a^5 - 2$

Tags: prime-numbers

How can i proof that $41$ does not divide $a^5 - 2$ for any $a \in \Bbb Z$?

I think i must show that $a^5 - 2$ is multiple of 41.

So if i do $(a^5 - 2) / 41$ i must get 0 rest?

I'm stuck sorry.

Thank you.

Comment: Do you know Fermat’s little theorem?

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. This is not a "do this for me" site. If you [edit] the question to show us what you tried and where you are stuck we may be able to help.

Comment: If $p$ is a prime and $a$ is any integer not divisible by p, then $a^{p-1} − 1$ is divisible by $p$. My question is how to prof the specific $a^5-2$. thankyou

Comment: What have you tried? EG Did you brute force check $ a =0, 1, 2, \ldots 40$?

Comment: isn't a multiple * 2 would have to be a fifth power remainder of division by 41 for it be a multiple, but you can  do no more than 20 cases and figure if it is if you know enough.

Answer (score 0):

If we were to have $a^5\equiv2\bmod41$,

then we would have $1\equiv a^{40}\equiv2^8=256=246+10\equiv10\bmod41$ -- a contradiction.